# Access vuex store getter in nuxt data

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

I need to set up some data in one of my pages in a Nuxt app but that data depends on the value of a variable that I am getting via a getter from my vuex store. Why can't I do it like this?

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      logo: this.currentPlayer.logo,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      currentPlayer: 'players/current',
    }),
  },
}
```

If I try and use this, I get

```
Property or method "logo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

Comment: `currentPlayer` is undefined at the moment of component creation because `data` is initially evaluated before `computed`

Comment: OK - that makes sense. So what's the recommended way around this? Declare logo as a computed value maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to assign a new value to `logo` at anytime in your logic, you can just make it a computed property and it should work fine:

```
computed: {
   ...mapGetters({
       currentPlayer: 'players/current',
   }),
    
   logo() {
       return this.currentPlayer?.logo;
   },
},
```

However, if you need to keep it inside `data` to be able to re-assign it later, you can work around it by initializing `logo` at the `mounted()` hook:

```
mounted() {
    this.logo = this.currentPlayer?.logo;
}
```